# How can I connect to facebook using a non popup Login page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have made the project about facebook-api using javascript and jquery.
I connected the facebook, but It must open a popup to do the login.

I want to make a non-popup login page. so How to solve this problem?

Comment: You could redirect to facebook, but in some way a page from facebook must be shown so the user can input credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be done with Javascript SDK, but maybe use PHP SDK to generate the signup link?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using the JavaScript SDK since it'll lose its session. However take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ this works about the same as the JavaScript SDK you'll just need to set a `Location` header to redirect the user.

Make sure you have specified the correct (absolute) `redirect_uri` when requesting a login url